# MassTransit.RabbitMQ - Connect Failed: Broker unreachable

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

After updating MassTransit packages to the latest version (4.1.0.1426-develop) I experience problems with registering more then 26 queues. For example, code below crushes with error

> [20:51:06 ERR] RabbitMQ Connect Failed: Broker unreachable:
>   guest@localhost:5672/test

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);

    var configuration = builder.Build();

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information("Starting Receiver...");

    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddSingleton(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
    {
        IRabbitMqHost host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://guest:guest@localhost:5672/test"), h => { });

        for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"receiver_queue{i}", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<TestHandler>();
            });
        }

        x.UseSerilog();
    }));

    var container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var busControl = container.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();

    busControl.Start();

    Log.Information("Receiver started...");
}
```

So, it can't register 27 queues. However it works if I decrease the number to 26 :)

If I downgrade MT NuGet packages to the latest stable 4.0.1 version it perfectly works and I can register up to 50 queues.

Also, another observation - with 4.1.0.1426-develop versions it takes much longer to start this very tiny app. However when I test it with latest stable 4.0.1 and try to create 50 queues it starts almost immediately.

Any ideas where this limitation came from and how to avoid it?

Comment: I suggest creating a reproduction repository on Github and opening an issue in MT repository.

Comment: Yeah, this is weird. I wonder why it would do such a thing. Limitations on Task.WhenAll perhaps? Hmm.

Comment: I opened issue here https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1078 as @Alexey Zimarev suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for opening the issue, that helps track it.

Also, it seems to be fixed now. There was an issue with how the netcoreapp2.0 program stack (and possibly the TaskScheduler) causing it to delay for a long period of time the Connect method in RabbitMQ.Client. I'm thinking this is a TPL/thread issue where the connection wasn't being scheduled for a good 15+ seconds, after which it completed immediately.

Moving it into a Task.Factory.StartNew() (deep inside the MT code) appears to have fixed the issue to where it doesn't fail, and it executes immediately.

Comment: Thank you a lot for such a quick fix!

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been marked as resolved but I ran into a similar issue.

> fail: MassTransit[0] partners.moneytransfer | RabbitMQ Connect Failed:
> serviceUser@rabbitmq:5672/

The only way I was able to resolve is, is by adding the user to the rabbitmq database with its username and password as specified in the Bus configuration.